# How do I force IE out of Quirks mode when I can't access the head of the page?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

I work for a large company and the site I'm updating has a templated header which can't be changed. The site loads in Quirks mode and I'd like to force just one page to load in IE9. Is there a way that this can be done?

I tried to dump this code into the body, because that's all I have access to, but it didn't work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Comment: check the HTTP headers, your IT dept may be sending an X-UA-Compatible header that would override the META tag. Also I would encourage you to get have your IT department look at IE 11's Enterprise Mode for those legacy applications that wont work in modern browsers, like the one you are working on. http://love2dev.com/#!article/Internet-Explorer-Enterprise-Mode-Resources

Comment: Unfortunately asking our IT department to do anything takes months and we were hoping to launch this page in a couple weeks. So without getting our IT department involved is there any code that I can use in the body of the html document that will force the document mode to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get IE 7 to open XHTML files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513034/how-do-i-get-ie-7-to-open-xhtml-files)